# How to Return a Field in the following order

Tags: node.js, graphql

Using GraphQL, write a query to return a book with an argument of ISBN which is equal to the string 0743273567. A book is retrieved from the database and converted into an object with the following structure:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXRyh.png)

For the book query, How can i  return the fields in the following order:

title, author, published, publisher, pages, genres, reviews

Answer (score 0):

Below query should work

```
query {
  book(ISBN: "0743273567") {
    title
    author
    published
    publisher
    pages
    genres
    reviews(limit: 1) {
      author
      date
      content
    }
  }
}
```

Actual implementation of the resolver function and the database query will depend on the specifics of your Node.js and database setup, but this query should work assuming those details are handled correctly.